# Why does it seem that INT_MIN and INT_MAX are out of range for type int?

Tags: c

When I use the INT_MAX and INT_MIN constants I get -2147483648 ... 2147483647.

But when I try to compute the maximum and minimum values for ints using this function:

```
static int computeInt(void)
{
    int myInt = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 32;

    for (int i = min; i < max; i++)
    {
        myInt = myInt + pow(2, i);
    }

    myInt = myInt / 2;

    return myInt;
}
```

I don't get the same number. I think the technical for what happens is that myInt overflows.

Thanks!

Comment: What number do you get?

Comment: when you do `pow(2, 31)` you cause signed integer overflow. Use larger data type instead, say `long`.

Comment: Pow() return double and you casting it to INT

Comment: You can compute `INT_MAX` by doing `myInt = (~0)>>1`. Then, `INT_MIN` is `- INT_MAX - 1`

Comment: @Rerito: `(~0)>>1` has implementation-defined result. It's common for it to be -1 (since implementations commonly do an arithmetic right shift on signed types). That's not actually guaranteed, though, so it *could* be `INT_MAX` on some implementations.

Comment: @SteveJessop : Yes, I noticed that while testing and corrected it in my answer (adding a cast to unsigned type). Anyway thanks for explaining the phenomenon

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have an overflow because the range for int is from -2^31 to 2^31 - 1 and you try to compute the sum of powers of 2 from 0 to 31. Your final value is the result of: `(2^0 + 2^1 + 2^3 + ... + 2^31) / 2` which is obviously greater than 2^31 - 1

Comment: Also, even if the final value was in range (e.g. subtracting an extra 1), there's still a problem that some of the intermediate values used in the working are out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is right. Your `int` overflows, because you keep adding to it. I'm not sure why you're using a loop, when the max int is simply 2^31-1 or `pow(2,31)-1`.

Using a loop you could do:

```
for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
    myInt = myInt * 2;
}
myInt = myInt - 1;
```

(Note that this loop also results in a temporary overflow. After the last iteration `myInt` will be `-2147483648`, but subtracting one will result in `2147483647`)

Comment: Don't you mean `pow(2,31)-1`?

Comment: Ahhhhh wow I feel semi retarded. Okay, so what's the minus 1 for?

Comment: Because with a 4 byte `int` (=32 bits) you can store 2^32 different numbers. With 2^31 negative numbers + 2^31-1 positive numbers + zero you have 2^32 numbers.

Comment: You should also check out this article: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: A signed int that overflows is undefined in C.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to detect the maximum signed integer reliably through arithmetic in this way because as soon as the integer exceeds `INT_MAX` the result is undefined (it could simply crash).

You can however work out the maximum unsigned integer, as this is guaranteed to wrap around back to 0, i.e. `UINT_MAX + 1` is guaranteed to be `0`. Similarly, `unsigned int a = -1` will equal `UINT_MAX`.

Since a signed `int` and `unsigned int` are guaranteed to use the same amount of storage and alignment, you could divide the calculated `UINT_MAX` by 2 to get `INT_MAX`. Therefore:

```
unsigned int maxint = -1;
maxint /= 2;
```

Comment: `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX` are guaranteed to be one less than a power of two and `UINT_MAX`/2=`INT_MAX`. This follows from the representation of integers. So, you could compute `UINT_MAX` and get `INT_MAX` from it.

Comment: I thought this myself, but I'm not certain that `INT_MAX` is guaranteed to be `UINT_MAX / 2`. If it is, I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: There's only one sign bit (per the standard) and padding bits are extinct (in practice).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I've adjusted the answer.

Comment: Per C spec `INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX` is specified.  `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX/2` is commonly true, but not specified.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the previous answers and comments, you have an overflow (even when assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`.
If you want to compute "manually" these constants, you could simply do this :

```c
int myInt = (((unsigned int)(-1)) >> 1);
int myIntMin = -myInt - 1;
```

This is not trully architecture independent as it assumes that signed integers are represented using 2's complement logic and that there is no padding bit in the integer representation. But in many cases, this should work fine (tested on x86 pc).

Comment: It's not *wholly* architecture independent. It relies on the implementation being "normal-looking" -- that there are no padding bits in either `int` or `unsigned int`, and that `int` uses 2's complement representation. These assumptions hold on pretty much all C implementations, but the reason the standard provides these constants isn't just to save you remembering the expressions in this answer, it's because they aren't guaranteed to work.

Comment: That's embarrassing, I was not aware of that. I am editing to make it accurate right away.

Comment: `int myIntMax = -1u/2;` is terser.